# Mock override when() behavior in loop

Tags: java, mocking

In my test I have the following loop :

```
for(B b:listOfB){
    when(future.get(anyLong(), any())).thenReturn(new A());
    Result res = C.process(B)
    assertNotNull("result is null although it shouldn't be", res);
    when(future.get(anyLong(), any())).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());
    b.setStatus("WAITING_FOR_PROCESS");
    Result res = C.process(B)
    assertNull("result expected to be null", res);
}
```

In the C.process method I'm using the future..

I'm getting in the **second iteration** in the loop on the **first "when"** an `java.lang.InterruptedException`. I tried to change the second when to :

```
    doThrow(new InterruptedException()).when(future).get(anyLong(), any());
```

but I got the same exception.

Any idea how can I solve the issue ? I understand the the exception is raised in the second iteration because when I set the "when" in the second iteration it "invokes" the future.get..